# How to put overflow-y in the textbox of a multiple selection dropdown

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

[image]

as you see I tried to add it in, but i get the following:

[image]

but the options were included in the overflow
[image]

put a scroll in the selected options box

Comment: Please don't share images of your code. Copy the code into the post instead.

Answer (score 0):

do you know that the `!Important` is badly written and should be `!important`?
I guess this is the problem, if not, my bad, just tried ot help.

Comment: youre right it is not spelled correctly, but it's just for an example of what i did before. I usually write it !important